# What is fully ramda.js equivalent of this code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

i need create function that updates item with certain id in list by merging payload object

**in ramda.js way**

```
export const updateItem = <T extends { id: I }, I>(items: T[], id: I, payload: Partial<T>) =>
  items.map(
    item => item.id === id
      ? ({ ...item, ...payload })
      : item
  )
```

Comment: What's your best attempt so far?  Also, what do  you mean by "in (the) ramda.js way"?  Are you looking for an entirely point-free solution, or do you just want, for some reason, to use Ramda functions in place of native ones?

Comment: @ScottSauyet
yes, maybe ramda js has function that apply func to list element that matches condition

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?  What didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can certainly write a fairly readable version in Ramda:

```js
const updateItem = (id, payload) => map (
  when (propEq ('id', id), mergeLeft (payload))
)


const items = [{foo: 'a', id: 1}, {foo: 'b', id: 2}, {foo: 'c', id: 1}, {foo: 'd', id: 4}]

console .log (updateItem (1, {bar: 'x'}) (items)) // updates all with id of 1
console .log (updateItem (2, {bar: 'x'}) (items))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {map, when, propEq, mergeLeft} = R                        </script>
```

We can read this as `map` over our input a function that `when` the `id` property equals (`propEq`) the `id` supplied, perform a `mergeLeft` on the `payload` and the current value.  `when` has an implicit understanding that if the condition doesn't match, it returns the value intact.

If you want an entirely point-free version of the initial approach, we could use the somewhat obscure `useWith`, like this:

```js
const updateItems = compose (map, useWith (when, [propEq ('id'), mergeLeft]))
```

I would probably prefer to write that like this, though:

```js
const updateItem = useWith (when, [propEq ('id'), mergeLeft])
const updateItems = compose (map, updateItem)
```

If you want to supply all arguments together, we could do this:

```js
const updateItem = (id, payload, xs) => 
  map (when (propEq ('id', id), mergeLeft (payload)), xs)
// ...
updateItem (1, {bar: 'x'}, items)
```

**OOPS!**: The following is completely wrong; see the [comment on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73770224/#comment130344429_73779080)

<del>All of these make the assumption that we are testing every element.  It does not assume that the `id` is unique.  If you want to do that, the answer from Chad S. would work, but I would prefer to do it slightly differently:</del>

```js
// ***********************************************
// * NOTE: This is entirely broken.  Do not use. *
// ***********************************************

const updateItems = (id, payload, xs) => 
  adjust (findIndex (propEq ('id', id), xs), mergeLeft (payload), xs)


const items = [{foo: 'a', id: 1}, {foo: 'b', id: 2}, {foo: 'c', id: 1}, {foo: 'd', id: 4}]

console .log (updateItems (1, {bar: 'x'}, items)) // only the first one.
console .log (updateItems (2, {bar: 'x'}, items))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {adjust, findIndex, propEq, mergeLeft} = R                </script>
```

<del>We could also move toward point-free on this version, but I think it would end up pretty ugly.  We could make `xs` implicit trivially, but anything else would make it less readable to my mind.</del>

**Update**

After that poor answer, I thought I owed an attempt at creating an only-the-first-match solution that actually works.  I personally wouldn't try to do this nearly so close to point-free, but here's one appoach:

```js
const updateItems = (id, payload) =>  chain (
  ifElse (equals (-1), nthArg (1), flip (adjust) (mergeLeft (payload))),
  findIndex (propEq ('id', id))
)

const items = [{foo: 'a', id: 1}, {foo: 'b', id: 2}, {foo: 'c', id: 1}, {foo: 'd', id: 4}]

console .log (updateItems (1, {bar: 'x'}) (items)) // only the first of multiple matches.
console .log (updateItems (2, {bar: 'x'}) (items)) // one match
console .log (updateItems (7, {bar: 'x'}) (items)) // no matches
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {chain, ifElse, equals, nthArg, flip, adjust, mergeLeft, findIndex, propEq} = R </script>
```

I would still choose the version at the top unless I found actual performance problems with it.

Comment: Fascinating! I've tried in the past to get rid of arguments and did not actually consider `useWith`. This is eye opening :D

Comment: @VLAZ: I generally find `useWith` and -- to a lesser extent -- `converge` to be trying too hard.  If it doesn't come naturally as point-free, then don't bother.  But they have their uses, and `lift` feels perfectly fine to me.  Don't ask me to explain these feelings, though; it's pretty fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

So first we want to find the index of the item we want to change:

```js
R.findIndex(R.propEq('id', id))
```

If that's -1 then we don't have to do anything (return the items). Otherwise we have to adjust the items by merging the payload into the item at that index.

```js
R.pipe(
  R.findIndex(R.propEq('id', id)), 
  R.ifElse(
    R.equals(-1), 
    R.always(R.identity), 
    R.adjust(R.__, R.mergeLeft(payload))
  )
)
```

Finally we just apply items to that pipe, and then apply items again to the result of the pipe:

```js
const updateItem = R.curry((id, payload, items) => {
  return R.converge(R.applyTo, [
    R.identity,
    R.pipe(
      R.findIndex(R.propEq('id', id)), 
      R.ifElse(
        R.equals(-1), 
        R.always(R.identity), 
        R.adjust(R.__, R.mergeLeft(payload))
      )
    )
  ])(items)
});
```

Comment: Two things: First, `when` and `unless` are good alternatives to `ifElse` when you want to perform some action on one branch but just return the input value intact otherwise.  Second, you don't really even need to branch here, since `adjust` is a no-op when supplied an index not in the array, such as `-1`.  See my answer for a simpler version.

Comment: You misunderstood why I used `R.always(R.identity)`. R.adjust WILL work just fine on -1. It will adjust the last item in the list which is not the one you want to adjust. I didn't use R.when because I wanted to RETURN R.identity (not call it).

Comment: Wow, one of the founders of Ramda, and I misremembered that fact about `adjust`.  I think I'll have to go, um, *adjust* my own answer!

Comment: No worries. It's hard to keep track of the specific details for such a large collection of functions. :)